# Any difference in nuance by the position of if-clause in a sentence?

Tags: meaning, differences, sentence-patterns

Does the position of if-clause in a sentence, either before or after the main clause, give the sentence any different implication?

For example, how do the two sentences below sound to the native speakers of English? Any difference, or no difference?

- *If I were you, I would ask her out for dinner.*
- *I would ask her out for dinner if I were you.*

Comment: No difference to me.

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting.

Comment: Not that the inclusion or omission of the comma in the second sentence *does* make a difference—at least to me. Although there is no difference to the two example sentences in general, I do think the two sentences have a difference because of the lack of a comma in the second one. (1) *I would ask her out to dinner if I were you* means you ***should*** ask her out to dinner, but (2) *I would ask her out to dinner, if I were you* means that, assuming I were you, I would ask her out to dinner. (*I would not do such things if I were you* is generally used as a term of obligation.)